# Power Off not working in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: shutdown, 19.10, display-manager

I just upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10. On the session manager login screen, the 'Power Off' and 'Restart' options seem to have no effect.

When I'm logged in as a user, the 'Power Off' command works. `shutdown now` also works fine.

I also tried a 19.10 virtual machine. It also has the problem where initiating 'Power Off' from the session manager screen seems to have no effect.

(I have seen other questions which sound related, but I don't think I'm in the same situation as those other users.)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known high importance [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1847896). It is also mentioned in the 19.10 [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes#Unable_to_shutdown_or_restart_from_the_log_in_screen).

It appears as if a fix has been committed and hopefully will be available in the next release.

At this point, we should be able to consider this issue on track for resolution.